# Change to Italic only one symbol in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, find-and-replace

I need to find all "ΔE" and change only "E" symbol to italic.

How can it be done by find and replace, because it make both ΔE italic?

Off course it can be done by changing all "ΔE" to italic, and then replace all "Δ" to normal. But is there option to make it at once?

[image: sample text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Word's Wildcard Find doesn't have a Positive Look-behind option (which is the term for the thing you're trying to do, to create a non-capturing group.)

As a workaround you can:

- Find and Replace `ΔE` to `Δ~` (or `Δ§`, or any character not used elsewhere in the Document)
- Find and Replace `~` with Italic format
- Find and Replace back `~` with `E`

Comment: This is much better option, to change to somethings completely not existing in text, like 'foobar1111aaa', and then replacing it to the something necessary.